# Determine if char is in a certain range?

Tags: java

I want to check if `ch`, which defin as a char `(char ch = ' ')`, is between 0x20 (space) to 0x7E (~).

I try many ways, but it gives me wrong answer.

For example:

```
if (ch > 0x20 or ch <0x7F) then

if (ch > ' ' or ch < '~') then
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: what ways have you tried? It should be pretty easy to write an if statement to do this.

Comment: What is this `or`? The -1 is for not giving a useful title or error message.

Answer (score 3):

```
if( ch >= 0x20 && ch <= 0x7e) {
 // ch is in your range
}
```

or

```
if( ch >= ' '  && ch <= '~') {
// ch is in your range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code finds all non-ascii characters.  IN this case they are removed, but you can modify the replace to do whatever you want.

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```